# variables in system() call C++

Tags: c++, arguments, system

I have a variable in argv[1] which I need to call inside another c++ file in such a way:

```
        system("./assemblerL.out", argv[1]);
```

this above is incorrect syntax as I am getting "too many arguments" errors.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`system` can take only one parameter, and that´s a whole line like entered in the shell
(well, not with everything a shell like Bash got, but that doesn´t matter here).

With C++, just use `std::string` to concat the parts:

```
system((std::string("./assemblerL.out ") + argv[1]).c_str());
```

Or, more readable:

```
std::string line = "./assemblerL.out ";
line += argv[1];
system(line.c_str());
```

Remember to make sure that `argv[1]` exists before using it.

Comment: Btw., apparently my link in the previous question *did* help. But if you still hate me, I can delete this.

Comment: I don't hate anyone. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try concatinating the command into a single string and then call system like :

```
char ch[50]="";
strcat(ch,"./assemblerL.out ");
strcat(ch,argv[1]);
system(ch);
```

Comment: And what if `argv[1]` has more than 50 characters?

Comment: we can increase the size of the array if we need to be sure or we can use malloc then

Comment: Why not just use C++?

Comment: Thanks for the pure C answer, Sourav

Answer (score 1):

`std::system` only takes one parameter, which must be the complete string you want to execute. Be aware that, if this is Linux, the result is achieved by invoking a sub-shell, so expansion/substitution may occur. You may want to consider the `exec` line of functions. For Windows, you may want to investigate CreateProcess.

You have several choices for building your command line:

```
// c-like
char buffer[1024];
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%s %s", "command", "argument");
system(buffer); // could be truncated

// c++ string based
std::string commandline = std::string(command) + std::string(argument);
system(commandline.c_str());

// stringbuffer
#include <sstream>
std::ostringstream buf;
buf << command << " " << argument;
system(buf.str().c_str());
```